# how to inject script into document <head> without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am building a browser extension and I have a function inside of `<script>` tags that modifies the DOM that I need to inject into the `<head>` of any given webpage. The entire function is a string(`"<script>function content blah blah</script>"`). I was using jquery to achieve this:

```
$('head').prepend(modFunction);
```

and this works fine. I would like to remove jQuery for a few reasons but when I try to create a `<script>` element to inject into the `<head>` with vanilla javascript everything fails. I have tried two methods so far:

1.

```
  var headSelector = document.querySelector('head');
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = modFunction;
  modFunction = el.firstChild;
  headSelector.insertBefore(modFunction, headSelector.firstChild);
```

2.`document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', modFunction);`

Both javascript attempts inject a `<script>` tag with the correct function into the `<head>`, however, neither executes the function. Not sure why jQuery is working and the vanilla javascript doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you're inserting the script dynamically, where you insert it is irrelevant really.. You might be better off sticking to the body.

Comment: From the source code above it looks like you're trying to insert a `div` not a `script` tag..

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('script'), document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]);` This will only work if you have an existing script tag in place, I'd assume you would since you would want this to run on load of the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few mistakes.

1. If your `modFunction` is a string that contains `<script>` tag before and after it, your code won't work, because changing `innerHTML` of `div` will not execute added scripts.
2. Using `insertAdjacentHTML` function is unneccesary, because `modFunction` is now object of type `Text`, which will insert `[object Text]` string before your script.
3. Instead, use `appendChild` function to insert properly new script element into head.

Although @Jantho1990 said that it is better to load script from file instead, many browsers use cache, so if you change your script source, it wont be always visible in browsers.

```
var scriptSource = '//YourScriptSource.....';
var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
scriptElem.text = scriptSource;
document.head.appendChild(scriptElem);
```

Comment: @duskwuff. No, it absolutely works. Try executing it before downvoting.

Answer (score -2):

SoftwareEngineer171's answer works (see text in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), but I would like to point out a couple of things:

1. You shouldn't be injecting `<div>` elements into the `<head>`. It's invalid HTML and a bad practice in general.
2. Generally, it is preferable to store your JavaScript on your server as a file and use the src attribute to get that file onto the page. Not only is that more secure, it also saves you a lot of work when you need to go back and update the code.

I would recommend the following solution:

yourJavaScriptFile.js

```
    function content blah blah
```

Inline:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yourJavaScriptFile.js"></script>
```